# Solving cubic equation modulo prime

Tags: elliptic-curves, cubics

I'm trying to an algorithm that can solve an elliptic curve equation for constant y:
$y^2 = x^3 + ax + b  \text{ mod } p$

p is 57 digits long

I've tried to solve it using like a regular cubic equation, but it's only return good results when the square root inside the formula for cubic equations has a solution mod p.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: [This thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/893044/11619) may help you. Jack's answer in particular.

Comment: Thank you. that was very helpful.