# How can one solve an equation over over a specific finite field?

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

How can one solve an equation of the following form where the coefficients are in $GF(2^{128})$?

$Az^3 + Bz^2 + Cz + D =  0$

The operations are defined over the same field.

Comment: Well, its a finite problem ...

Comment: Does Cardano's cubic formula work over a finite field?

Comment: @GregoryGrant maybe it works over the algebraic closure

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Then one could find the solutions in the closure $\overline{GF(2^{128})}$ and see if they are in $GF(2^{128})$.

Comment: To the extent that Cardano depends on the usual formula for solutions of a quadratic it cannot possibly work because the quadratic formula depends on our ability to complete the square. To do that we need to be able to divide by two, but this time $2=0$, so...

Comment: A general quadratic over a finite field of characteristic two is usually solved using the so called half-trace - a partial inverse to the 2-to-1 mapping $x\mapsto x^2+x$.

Comment: I'm looking for a general procedure to solve this kind of equations with arbitrary degrees.

Comment: I think there is an analogue of Berlekamp's algorithm for this job. See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/893044/11619). [Jack D'Aurizio's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/893074/11619) in particular. This time we might want to use the kernel of the trace as a way of selecting a "random half" of the elements of a field instead of using quadratic residues as a halving method. I'm a bit ashamed for not knowing in advance whether that will work.

Comment: See [Berlekamp's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%27s_algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

A rough sketch of a method that I think I could implement (given enough time and motivation). It is not deterministic, and it is probably nowhere near state of the art.

Let $K=GF(2^{128})$. Consider the trace mapping $tr:K\to GF(2)$ defined as the sum of iterates of the Frobenius automorphism
$$
tr(x)=x+x^2+x^4+x^8+x^{16}+\cdots+x^{2^{127}}=\sum_{i=0}^{127}x^{2^i}.
$$
For all $z\in K$ we have either $tr(z)=0$ or $tr(z)=1$ with both values appearing equally frequently. Because the trace is the sum of automorphisms it is a homomorphism of additive groups, $tr(x+y)=tr(x)+tr(y)$.
Let $H\subseteq K$ be the kernel of the trace. It is subspace over the prime field $GF(2)$, of dimension 127.

The task at hand is to find the zeros ($\in K$) of the given cubic
$$
p(x)=Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D\in K[x].
$$
The method I describe actually works for all low degree polynomials provided that all the roots of $p(x)$ are simple. That can be checked by calculating the gcd of $p(x)$ and $p'(x)$. There is general method for writing $p(x)$ as a product of square free factors, but I'm afraid I don't remember how it goes.

It is well known that all the elements of $K$ are zeros of the polynomial
$q(x)=x^{2^{128}}-x$. It is easy to see that the zeros of $p(x)$ that are also elements of $K$ are exactly the zeros of
$$p_0(x)=\gcd(q(x),p(x)).$$
The calculation of this gcd may look prohibitive, but it actually has a reasoanbly low complexity. This is because if $r_k(x)$ is the remainder
of $x^{2^k}$ modulo $p(x)$, then
$$
r_{k+1}(x)\equiv r_k(x)^2\pmod {p(x)}.
$$
In other words calculating the remainder of $q(x)$ modulo $p(x)$ only needs 128 squarings of low degree polynomials modulo the given cubic. We actually never need to carry out long division for polynomials of degrees higher than $2(\deg p(x) -1)$. After the initial computation Euclid's algorithm will only ever need to do long division of low degree polynomials, which has reasonable complexity.

Ok, so assume that we know $p_0(x)$. For all we know it could still be a cubic (or higher) that we cannot solve using a formula. The next step is non-deterministic. We pick a random element $\alpha\in K, \alpha\neq0$.
We want to $p_0(x)$ into two factors
$$
p_0(x)=p_1(x)r_1(x)
$$
such that $p_1(x)$ has as its zeros those zeros of $p_0(x)$
that are in the subspace $\alpha^{-1}H$. This means that
$$
p_1(x)=\gcd(p_0(x),tr(\alpha x)).
$$
Here the polynomial $tr(\alpha x)$ again has a disgustingly high degree, but its terms are all squares of the preceding one, so the sum of their remainders modulo $p_0(x)$ can be calculated with a reasonably complexity.

Given $p_1(x)$ we can find $r_1(x)$ by long division.

If either $p_1(x)$ or $r_1(x)$ is of degree one, we can find its zero (using the half-trace trick we could also find the zeros of a quadratic). Next we continue with the remaining non-linear factors by selecting another random $\alpha$ and repeating the above calculations.

Does this work? There may be pitfalls, but do observe that if $\alpha\neq\beta$, then the spaces $\alpha^{-1}H$ and $\beta^{-1}H$ intersect in a codimension one subspace. Therefore the bits of information about the identity of a zero of $p(x)$ obtained by using these two variants of the trace are independent from each other. I haven't checked out everything, but I think this means that random choices of $\alpha$:s should work sooner rather than later.

[I hope to add a toy example with $GF(16)$ here, but it will have to wait for tomorrow or may be a bit more.]

Comment: This just has to be known. Berlekamp probably has something betterm but I need to spend a while studying Lidl & Niederreiter, before I can say anything precise. Thanks for making me think about this. Sorry that I cannot say more.

Comment: a professorial hint, truly noble spirit.