# How can I determine if a polynomial is factorizable in $Z_p[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, prime-numbers, integers

First of all, sorry for my bad English.

> I am looking for a general method to know for which primes $p$ a specific polynomial factorize in $Z_p[x]$.

For example my teacher considers $(x^3-1)=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ and wants to factorize $x^2+x+1$. He considers $p=5$ and replaces all elements of $Z_5$ instead of $x$; $x^2+x+1$ is never zero, so does not factorize. For $p=13$ he obtains zero, so in $Z_{13}$ the polynomial factorizes. Then he proves that it is possible to factorize $x^2+x+1$ in $Z_p$ if and only if $p \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$. In the first direction of the proof (polynomial factorize in $Z_p$ implies $p \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$) he takes a $z$ in $Z_p$ that is a zero for $x^2+x+1$ and implies that $z^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. Why?

If I have a different polynomial in $Z_p$ there is a general method to determine the equivalence class of $p$ like in the example? It maybe involves the polynomial's degree?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is the problem that you don't understand how $z^3 \equiv 1 \pmod p$ is obtained?

Comment: We have $x^3-1=(x^2+x+1)(x-1)=0$, so $x^3=1$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$ for this $z$.

Comment: To learn about *algorithms* see the Wikipedia article [Factorization of polynomials over finite fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials_over_finite_fields), and see any book on computer algebra for details, e.g. Kaltofen, Zippel, etc.

Comment: I once posted a [toy example](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/893044/11619) of a run of Cantor-Zassenhaus algorithm. The goal there was to find zeros. Finding higher degree factors can also be done, but judging from your post this may be a bit advaced for you at the moment (try those again a bit later!). You can handle cubics over small fields by lookig for zeros, and quadratics modulo a larger prime using the law of quadratic reciprocity. With other specific polynomials I usually look for a trick first (like those on cyclotomic polynomials). If that fails I fire up my copy of Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the [Berlekamp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp's_algorithm) can give us a factorization of a given polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ for a prime $p$. If you want results for all $p$, there is no easy general congruence condition in general. For cyclotomic polynomials however see the discussion in
 [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305111/irreducible-cyclotomic-polynomial). Sometimes we obtain easy conditions, e.g., the polynomial $x^4+1$ is for *no* prime $p$ irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77155/irreducible-polynomial-which-is-reducible-modulo-every-prime).

Comment: Thank you. So he determines that the polynomial factorizes only for p=1(mod3) using the algorithm? For example if the polynomial is x^2+1 I think that p must be p=1(mod4), but I only understood that using numers, do I have to prove the double implication every time? Ps: i only need to know if the polynomial factorize, don't need to know the factors.

Answer (score 1):

There is a general method for prime $p$ and
$$ a x^2 + bx + c $$
given by repeating the derivation of the Quadratic Formula. For primes $p \neq 2$ and $$ b^2 - 4 a c \neq 0 \pmod p, $$
we can factor when there is an ordinary integer $t$ such that
$$ t^2 \equiv b^2 - 4 a c \pmod p.  $$ Notice that, if $p | a,$ we may then take $t=b,$ but the thing is no longer quadratic anyway.

I would guess you will learn the Legendre symbol and quadratic reciprocity next.

After quadratics, it gets very hard, even for cubic polynomials. Unless you want a computer to do the factoring for you, which will work for one prime at a time, you may be dealing with class field theory, advanced material. For example
$$  x^3 - x + 1 $$
is irreducible for primes 
$$ p = 2 u^2 + uv + 3 v^2,  $$ for some integers $u,v.$ I don't recall what happens when $p=23.$
The cubic factors into three distinct linear factors for
$$ p =  u^2 + uv + 6 v^2.  $$ Then $  x^3 - x + 1 $ factors as a linear times a quadratic when Legendre symbol $(-23|p) = -1.$

There are just a few examples of cubics where one may use reciprocity laws without resorting to class field theory. Ireland and Rosen do this one, proved by Gauss: 
$$  x^3 - 2 $$
is irreducible for primes 
$$ p = 4 u^2 + 2uv + 7 v^2,  $$ for some integers $u,v.$ 
The cubic factors into three distinct linear factors for
$$ p =  u^2  + 27 v^2.  $$ Then $  x^3 - 2 $ factors as a linear times a quadratic when Legendre symbol $(-3|p) = -1.$

Jacobi proved: 
$$  x^3 - 3 $$
is irreducible for primes 
$$ p = 7 u^2 + 3uv + 9 v^2,  $$ for some integers $u,v.$ 
The cubic factors into three distinct linear factors for
$$ p =  u^2  + uv + 61 v^2.  $$ Then $  x^3 - 3 $ factors as a linear times a quadratic when Legendre symbol $(-3|p) = -1.$