# roots of polynomial over finite field

Tags: roots, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Given a irreducible polynomial $f$ of degree $n$ over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p}$. How do I find any root $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ of $f$?
Is there a better way than trying out every element of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$?

Comment: Are coefficients in $\mathbb F_p$ or in $\mathbb F_{p^n}$?

Comment: The coeffecients are in $\mathbb{F}_p$

Comment: How is the field $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ given? How large are $p$ and $n$ in the case that interests you? An irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ over $\Bbb{F}_p$ has exactly $n$ roots in $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$. They form a single orbit under the action of the Galois group (iterates of Frobenius).

Comment: I have not worked too much with finite fields, but maybe something like a companion matrix over field elements could work?

Comment: If it has a root, it won't be irreducible in $\mathbb F_{p^n}$.

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb F_{p^n}$ be a root of $f$, ie. $f(\alpha) = 0$. We carry out division with remainder, dividing $f$ by the polynomial $(x - \alpha)$:

$$
f(x) = (x - \alpha)q(x) + \beta,~~~~~~~ \beta \in \mathbb F_{p^n}
$$

Inserting $x = \alpha$ in the above equation proves $\beta = 0$ and $f = (x - \alpha)q$, contradicting irreducibility.

On the other hand, if the root is not in $\mathbb F_p$ and the coefficients of $f$ are in $\mathbb F_p$, then $f$ may be irreducible in $\mathbb F_p$.

Comment: @Cloudscape: The OP spelled out that it is irreducible **over $\Bbb{F}_p$**

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes but it could have been forgotten in the subscript.

Comment: If the bigger field is given in some other way you can try factoring $f$ over that bigger field. The linear factors correspond to zeros. There are factoring algorithms.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, but factoring is doing a lot more than I need and thus will probably be even slower than just trying every value

Comment: Factoring is faster than trying every value. See e.g. [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/893044/11619).

Answer (score 2):

There are several methods to find roots of (irreducible) polynomials over finite fields, which are better than just testing every element. For example, the article [Finding roots of polynomials over finite fields](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0ahUKEwic-Ke2kf7SAhVlD8AKHfcVD40QFghNMAY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.100.2874%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&usg=AFQjCNGNAxOWt3viNt5McqZ8bhhunx99fw&sig2=o49lS3dAJUPghpjGGDeASA) explains the *fast polynomial evaluation algorithm*, with some examples of primitive polynomials over $GF(2)$.