# Cubic roots modulus prime

Tags: finite-fields, congruences

Suppose a,b,c are the cubic roots of:

x^3=1 mod p

where p is prime. One of the roots is obviously 1. Let a=1 then I'm wondering that:

b^2=c mod p

and

c^2=b mod p

and

a+b+c=p

and

b+c=p-1

I'm trying to understand if there is a polinomial algorithm (when p is known) to find b and c.

Regards Massimo.

Comment: Sorry I missed an if ... if b^2=c mod p then c^2=b mod p then...

Comment: There is a set of links at the bottom of your question. One them is "[edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2491587/edit)" which you can use to make updates so that your question is clear.

Comment: Sorry joffan I've missed the edit link

Comment: There is a tag line under your question which at the moment says `(finite-fields)  (congruences)` (but should probably say `(elementary-number-theory) (modular arithmetic)` ) and the next line down will probably read `share cite edit` and each of those words are links. But also here is another link: [$\large\color{blue}{\text{edit}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2491587/edit)

Answer (score 2):

You can find those cubic roots of unity either by following the non-deterministic algorithm of calculating $z=a^{(p-1)/3}$ modulo $p$ for a range of random numbers $a>1$. Unless $a$ is a cubic residue then $z$ will be a solution of $z^2+z+1\equiv 0\pmod p$. Observe that using square-and-multiply the calculation of $a^{(p-1)/3}$ for a fixed $a$ can be done in polynomial time (polynomial in $\log_2p$). Alternatively you can look for an algorithm to calculate $\sqrt{-3}$ modulo $p$, and then apply the quadratic formula. Sorry I can't point you right away at an efficient method for doing that. May be the links [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/893044/11619) help?

---

Adding hopefully illuminating examples of the techniques. For the purposes of illustration let's do the case $p=103$. Then $3\mid p-1$ guaranteeing the existence of third roots of unity modulo $p$. We also have $p\equiv3\pmod4$ implying that $-1$ is not a quadratic residue. This will simplify my other demonstration.

Let's first run the (non-deterministic) method of calculating powers $2^{(p-1)/3}$. Here $(p-1)/3=34$. It is our lucky day, and it turns out that the smallest choice $a=2$ will work. All the calculations below are modulo $103$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
2^2&=&&\equiv4,\\
2^4&=(2^2)^2&=4^2&\equiv16,\\
2^8&=(2^4)^2\equiv16^2&\equiv256&\equiv50,\\
2^{16}&=(2^8)^2\equiv50^2&=2500&\equiv28,\\
2^{32}&=(2^{16})^2\equiv28^2&=784&\equiv63,\\
2^{34}&=2^{32}\cdot2^2\equiv63\cdot4&=252&\equiv46.
\end{aligned}
$$
Because the result $\neq1$ we can conclude that $b=46$ is a cubic root of unity. Joffan explained that the other must be $c=103-1-b=56$. We can check your claim easily:
$$
b^2=46^2=2116\equiv 2116-20\cdot103=56=c.
$$

---

The other method I show needs $p\equiv3\pmod4$ (in addition to $p\equiv1\pmod6$). I want to find a solution of the congruence 
$$x^2\equiv-3.\qquad(*)$$
Because the solutions of $b^2+b+1\equiv0$ are $b=(-1\pm\sqrt{-3})/2$ and we know that those solutions exist, we also know that $(*)$ has two non-congruent solutions. We could just observe that in this case $10^2\equiv-3$, but that would be cheating, so let's not use that. A key ingredient is that $-1$ is a quadratic non-residue modulo $p$. As the two solutions of $(*)$ are negatives of each other, this means that exactly one of those solutions is a quadratic residue modulo $p$. But the quadratic residues are exactly the zeros of the polynomial $x^{(p-1)/2}-1$. Here $(p-1)/2=51$, so to find the solution $d$ of $(*)$ that is also a quadratic residue, all we need to do is to calculate the gcd of the polynomials $f(x)=x^2+3$ and $g(x)=x^{51}-1$. That gcd must then be a constant multiple of $(x-d)$! The Euclidean algorithm will do that actually very quickly. The only time consuming part is to calculate the remainder of $x^{51}-1$ modulo $x^2+3$. That is no worse than a single run of square-and-multiply. This is because
$$
x^2\equiv-3\pmod{f(x)},
$$
so
$$
x^{50}=(x^2)^{25}\equiv(-3)^{25}\pmod{f(x)}.
$$
A square and multiply shows that $(-3)^{25}\equiv-31\pmod{103}$. Therefore
$$
g(x)=x^{51}-1=x(x^{50})-1\equiv-31x-1\pmod{f(x)}.
$$
We knew in advance that $\gcd(f(x),g(x))$ is linear, so it has to be a constant multiple of $31x+1$. A run of extended Euclidean algorithm (hopefully you are familiar with that) gives that the modular inverse of $31$ is $10$. We can easily check this: $10\cdot31=310\equiv310-3\cdot103=1$.

Therefore the monic gcd is
$$
\gcd(x^2+3,x^{51}-1)=x+10.
$$
This has the obvious zero $d=-10$, which can then serve in the role of $\sqrt{-3}$ modulo $103$. Therefore the solutions of $b^2+b+1=0$ are
$$
b=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{-3}}2=\frac{-1\pm(-10)}2=
\begin{cases}-11/2\equiv (103-11)/2=46&,\text{and}\\
9/2\equiv(103+9)/2=56.\end{cases}
$$

---

There may be something better out there, but when these algorithms apply, they have polynomial complexity.

Comment: I'm fairly sure it is known that a non-cubic residue $a$ can be found below a bound of the form $O((\log p)^k)$, but I cannot point at specific bound. If $a$ is a primitive root that will surely work,so looking for bounds on the smallest primitive root should give more hits. Anyway, I think the non-deterministic can be made deterministic with complexity that is polynomial in $\log p$.

Comment: Oh yes jyrki I will try to translate in python you methods thanks.

Comment: Jyrki thank's a lot very useful explanation, I wrote a small python script and the "non deterministic" method (that is more general) works very well and it is very fast. The fact is due to $a$ remain little (2 or 3 no more in my brief tests) even for big primes such as $p \approx   2^{256} $

Comment: I have implemented the deterministic method and I found that the square root of -3 can be computed (when p mod 4=3) simply by computing $-3^{(p+1)/4} (mod) p$. Works for all $p = 3 (mod) 4$. Using square and multiply as in the first non deterministic method the algorithm works in polinomial time. Note that you also have to reduce $b^2+b+1=0 (mod) p$.

Answer (score 1):

With $p$ prime and $p\equiv 1 \bmod 3$, you will have three cubic roots of $1$, $\{1,b,c\}$, taking $1<b,c<p$. The first non-unity root determines the other one since we know $b^2\not\equiv 1$ and $(b^2)^3\equiv (b^3)^2 \equiv 1^2\equiv 1 \bmod p$, so $c\equiv b^2$.

Also of course $c^2\equiv b^4\equiv b^3\cdot b\equiv b\bmod p$.

Then given that $b\ne 1$ we know that $b{-}1$ is coprime to $p$ and so $(b-1)(1+b+b^2) = b^3-1 \equiv 0 \bmod p$ implies $(1+b+b^2) \equiv 0 \bmod p$. Then given that $1+b+c<2p$ we must have $1+b+c=p$.

You would need to define what you mean by a polynomial algorithm to get any useful answer there.

Comment: +1 for addressing the main question. My guess is that by *a polynomial algorithm* he means an algorithm that take $O((\log p)^n)$ steps for some constant $n$, but it may be better that they clarify.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answers, here is the format definition of polinomial time: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolynomialTime.html

Comment: Jyrki we also have that b^3=1 mod p and c^3=1 mod p and obviously a^3=1 mod p