# factors of $X^{p^n}-X$

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I'm my study of Galois theory I have been struggling with the following proposition without much success:

> The polynomial $X^{p^n}-X$ is precisely the product of all the distinct irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ of degree $d$ where $d$ runs through all divisors of $n$

For example, $X^{p^6}-X$ is factorized by a polynomial of degree 1, 2, 3 and 6? It is posible to obtain them explicitly?

Comment: You probably mean mod $p$. And the answer depends in $p$. Start here: [Cyclotomic polynomial - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial)

Comment: @lhf yep edited for $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$. I'm going to read about your link. Thanks.

Comment: If $\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha) = \mathbb{F}_{p^6}$ then what is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ ?

Comment: @reuns as far I know, it must be a polynomial of degree 6

Comment: And $\alpha^{p^l}$ is a root of it, so that polynomial is $\prod_{l=0}^5 (X-\alpha^{p^l})$

Comment: Finding those factors is possible but somewhat taxing. If the only input you are given is: **Factor $x^{p^n}-x$!** then I would go with [the Cantor-Zassenhaus algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_algorithm). Works for any polynomial over any finite field! But, if $p$ and/or $n$ are largish it will be a lot of work. [This toy example I did when learning about C-Z](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/893882/11619) will show what to expect.

Comment: (cont'd) Except in the smallest cases this is a job for computers. But, you rarely have a need for **all** the factors anyway. Also, if you know one irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ you can find other factors of $x^{p^n}-x$ by the process of constructing the field $\Bbb{F}_q$ with it, and then calculating the minimal polynomials of random elements.