# factor cyclotomic polynomial over GF(2)

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

factor cyclotomic polynomial explicitly where  $Φ_{17} (X)$ over $\mathrm{GF}(2) $

$(x-1)^{m(17/1)} (x^{17}-1)^{m(17/17)}$ 
How can I complete my steps

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Do you mean *cyclotomic*?  Are you familiar with [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+x%5E17-1)?

Comment: i mean next step of solution over GF(2)  , i don't mean factor x^17-1

Comment: ${ _{17} (X) over GF(2) }$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives the answer to that too -- look carefully

Comment: Using the piece of theory I outlined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/305123/11619) you can show that your polynomial will have two factors of degree eight. This also follows from the cyclicity of the multiplicative groups of finite fields - you look for the smallest integer $m>0$ such that $17\mid 2^m-1$. Furthermore, you can figure out whether the two factors are each others reciprocals or self-reciprocal i.e. palindromic. That will give you a lot of information fo work with.

Comment: And if the educated guessing from the previous comment fails to give you a useful system of equations (in the unknown coefficients of the factors), you can apply a factorization algorithm on it. For an on site example of Berlekamp's algorithm look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3055108/11619). I don't know whether Mathematica/Wolfram Alpha uses Berlekamp or the somewhat faster but non-deterministic [Cantor-Zassenhaus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_algorithm).

Comment: Last but not least. Welcome to the site! To make sure your questions don't attract negative attention please study [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).

Comment: thank you for your advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Berlekamp algorithm over $\Bbb F_2$ we have
$$
\Phi_{17}(X)=1+X+X^2+\cdots +X^{16}=(X^8 + X^7 + X^6+X^4 +X^2+X+1)(X^8 + X^5 + X^4+X^3+1).
$$

Comment: This agrees with Wolfram Alpha ;-)

Comment: This is good news for Wolfram Alpha. We can trust it.