# How to determine whether a polynomial has roots modulo a prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> How to determine if a polynomial has roots modulo a prime?

I was attempting to find solutions to this polynomial $x^3+x^2-4\equiv 0$ mod($7$)

The only method I currently know to determine solutions is to try every element in the complete residue system. There are none.

However given $x^3+x^2-4\equiv 0$ mod($10007$), ($10007$ is a prime)

I would have no idea how to find roots of this polynomial or if they even exist.

Comment: do you mean specifically real roots?

Comment: This is close to being a duplicate of [this older thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/893044/11619). I give a toy example of a run of Cantor-Zassenhaus in an answer there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to count the solutions for $f(x)\equiv0\pmod p$ (where $p$ is prime) is to compute the gcd of $f(x)$ and $x^p-x$ over the field $\Bbb F_p$ of $p$
elements. This gcd is $g(x)=\prod_{a\in R}(x-a)$ where $R$ is the set of roots of $f$ in $\Bbb F_p$.

This may seem daunting if $p$ is large. But as long as $f$ has small degree
one can start by reducing $x^p-x$ modulo $f(x)$ over $\Bbb F_p$. Doing the
$x^p$ modulo $f(x)$ is just like computing $a^k$ modulo $m$ for large $m$
and can be done by the [binary powering algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).