# Finding 1 solution of $(x^3 + ax + b) \bmod p = 0$

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptography

I am writing unit-tests for an elliptic curve implementation (secp256r1 / prime256v1) and need to find a curve point with $y = 0$ to reach coverage for an edge case (special handling of curve points with $y = 0$ during point doubling).

The curve is defined as

$$
y^2 \bmod p \equiv x^3 + ax + b \bmod p
$$

with p, a and b being fixed constants

$$
p=115792089210356248762697446949407573530086143415290314195533631308867097853951
$$

$$
a=115792089210356248762697446949407573530086143415290314195533631308867097853948=-3 \mod p
$$

$$
b=41058363725152142129326129780047268409114441015993725554835256314039467401291
$$

and I must find

$$
0 \bmod p \equiv x^3 + ax + b \bmod p
$$

I would appreciate your help. If you know a solution or a database (I think this is a common edge case for this named elliptic curve), please let me know :)

Best regards,
Dustin

Comment: Nicely asked question

Comment: I doubt there is a method other than checking all values $x=0,\cdots,p-1.$ Even a simpler equation, $x^2+ax+b\equiv 0\pmod p$ doesn't have a simple formula - it amounts to finding a square root of $a^2-4b$ modulo $p,$ and I don't know any quick method for that other than squaring $0,1,\dots,\frac{p-1}2.$

Comment: We might have a rule for figuring out if such an $x$ exists, however.

Comment: For example, if you compute $\gcd(x^p-x,{x^3+ax+b})$ and get a value other than $1,$ then there is such an $x.$ If the gcd is of the form $x+c,$ this will also give you the root, but th GCD might give $x^3+ax+b,$ if there are three distinct roots, or $x^2+cx+d,$ in which case there are two distinct roots with one repeated (and then you should be able to find a root.)

Comment: Calculating the GCD might seem complicated, but we can solve the division of $x^p-x$ by $x^3+ax+b$ by calculating $x^p\bmod(x^3+ax+b)$ using repeated squaring, which takes $O(\log p)$ time.

Comment: You can find the solution(s), if any with for example the Cantor-Zassenhaus algorithm. It is an extension of the method outlined in two comments by Thomas Andrews. In the annoying case of a cubic with three solutions, C-Z proceeds by (non-deterministically?) distinguishing roots $x$ such that $x-r$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$. You simply select random $r$s until you get lucky (a single test value of $r$ gives you something with probability at least 50 per cent). See [this older thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/893044/11619) for links to more. I did a small case as an example.

Comment: FYI. There is https://neuromancer.sk/std/secg/secp256r1 for a good listing of the standard curves. In Cryptography, we divide the curves into prime and non-prime curves. Prime curves have prime order, so there are no order 2 elements ( y=0). Non-prime curves can have order two elements like Curve25519. This is necessary for the Montgomery ladder...

Comment: Your real issue is the point of infinity and side-channel resistance. You may need to look at Joyce Ladder for side channel implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica does not find any solutions to the equation $x^3-3x+b=0$ in the field $\Bbb{F}_p$. This is just as well because [the order of this curve $n$](https://www.secg.org/SEC2-Ver-1.0.pdf), see page 16 of the linked document, is an odd integer. When the cofactor $h=1$, the order of $G$ is the order of the curve. But for a curve in the short Weierstrass form, a point with $y=0$ would be of order two, implying that $2\mid n$ by Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct approach. The curve is prime and there are no order 2 elements that are found by setting $y=0$. One can visit Washingtons' book section 3.1 Torsion points for this.

Answer (score 0):

If $P=(x,0)\in E$ for some $x$, then $-P=(x,-0) = (x,0) = P$, hence

$$P+P={\cal O}_E$$

The algorithm for adding points would first check whether you are trying to add $P$ to $-P$, and if so (which is the case for such specific $P$), return ${\cal O}_E$.  Hence, the algorithm would never enter the usual computation of $2P$ that requires the computation of $$\lambda = \dfrac{3x_P^2+a}{2y_P}$$

So when computing $\lambda$, it holds that `assert (y != 0)`, and you'll never succeed in covering the computation of $\lambda$ with $y=0$ (except there is a bug elsewhere in the code).